# What is the sql statement to create a new database call "project", while you're on mysql command prompt?

Tags: mysql

What is the sql statement to create a new database call "project", while you're on mysql command prompt?

Comment: What does this have to do with "PDF generation"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have corrected your tags to the question. if you feel there are others that apply please add them. If your question is actually about pdf-generation please provide details about that topic and add that tag back to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE DATABASE database_name;` [See the manual...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)

Answer (score 1):

use the command : Create Database project